# Updating SwiftUI view from Core Data non scalar attribute

Tags: core-data, swiftui, observedobject

I have a Core Data NSManagedObject entity `Person` with a Bool attribute that I generate as a NSNumber. (the "Use Scalar Type" checkbox is not used, so the Bool attribute becomes an NSNumber)
I am trying to observe this attribute, `employed`, to control the UI.

`@ObservedObject var person: Person`

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        Section {
            HStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $person.employed) { <-- 1
                    Text("Showing employed content..")
                }
            }
        }
        if person.employed.boolValue {
            Section { } etc
```

I get a warning at "1" saying: `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<NSNumber?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'`
How can I make use of the `employed` attribute as a bool without changing it to a scalar?

Note: `$person.employed.boolValue` would not work it seems, and I would also have to account for the optional part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do it is via a custom `Binding`:

```
Toggle("Showing employed content..", isOn: Binding<Bool>(get: {
         person.employed?.boolValue == true
      }, set: { value in
         person.employed = NSNumber(value: value)
      }))
```

Now, if you prefer this to be a computed property instead, you could do something like this:

```
var isEmployed: Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool>(get: {
        person.employed?.boolValue == true
    }, set: { value in
        person.employed = NSNumber(value: value)
    })
}

var body: some View {
    Toggle("Showing employed content..", isOn: isEmployed)
}
```

Also, here is a possible implementation of an extension that handles optional `NSNumber` backed booleans (excuse my terible naming):

```
extension Binding where Value == NSNumber? {
    var boolBinding: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding<Bool>(get: {
            self.wrappedValue == true
        }, set: { value in
            self.wrappedValue = NSNumber(value: value)
        })
    }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
Toggle("Showing employed content..", isOn: $person.employed.boolBinding)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alladinian for the answer. It works great. I'd love to have this factored out to make it cleaner, but it seems the solution provided by vadian above doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I ended up fetching the NSManagedObject directly within SwiftUI:     `@FetchRequest(fetchRequest:Person.anyFetchRequestHere) var person: FetchedResults<Person>`

Comment: @Zsolt Glad that helped you. I've updated the answer to include some more options.